# Does Error k come from Angular or Electron?

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I am using Angular 10 in my Electron app and after building a release version of my app I see the following errors below in the Chrome Inspector. Unfortunately I have no idea if it comes from Electron or Angular, or what it even tries to tell me. The non-production build just runs fine without the error.

Unfortunately I can't really see the stacktrace. Does anyone know what it is, or has a good approach how to pinpoint the cause of it? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the app work in dev mode? I mean without production build?

Comment: Yes, the error does not show up in a dev build. I will add this to my question

Comment: You can click on the arrow next to 'k'. It should give you a more detailed info what happened

Comment: Thanks so much! I just saw it's missing an issue. You made my day. I would accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the arrow next to 'k'. It gives you a more detailed info about the error and what might have happened.